# How use HWIOAuthBundle Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, oauth-2.0

I used this tutorial https://gist.github.com/danvbe/4476697 to create integration between HWIOAuthBundle and FosUserBundle but I don't know how to create a page where put inside botton or link to authenticate users by facebook. If I go to this link app_dev.php/login I can only see a normal form with username and password.

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a link to any of the "login-check" pages and that route should handle the authentication like...

```
<a href="{{ path('facebook_login') }}">Login Using Facebook</a>
```

Comment: Why did you write: path('facebook_login') if route pattern is:/login/check-facebook ?

Comment: The path name is `facebook_login`, that's what you put in the `path()` function. If you use route names then you can change the patterns and still keeping links active.

Comment: in which file can I find facebook_login routes?

Comment: The routes are in the `routing.yml` file - https://gist.github.com/danvbe/4476697#file-routing-yml

Comment: Thankyou. I tried also to make path('hwi_oauth_redirect'), because hwi_oauth_redirect is in routing.yml but doesn't work.Why?

Comment: `hwi_auth_redirect` is the name of the parent route, essentially just a holder but still needs a unique name. The actual routes are in the file at `@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/redirect.xml` (https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/routing/redirect.xml)